# downcast from CLplacemark? to Clplacemark only unwraps optional

Tags: swift2

How can I fix this error:

> "downcast from CLplacemark? to Clplacemark only unwraps optional"

This is my code:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

    if (error == nil) {

        if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks?[0] as! CLPlacemark){}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `as! CLPlacemark` there is not need to cast something to exactly the same type....but you could also do this too:

```
if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks.first as? CLPlacemark){}
```

This protects you from the array being empty and having your app crash if `placemarks[0]` is nil